# Trying to get property of non-object on NotORM

Tags: php, notorm

I am using `Slim Framework` and `NotORM` on my Sales Monitoring System Project. When I run my program, I get a Slim Application Error: `"Trying to get property of non-object" on line 179`.

I cannot fix the error.

here is my code:

```
$select = $db->pssale->select("F8")->where("F8 = ?","$textdate")->fetch();
                            $count = count($select);
```

Comment: Usually means that you're trying to access something (a property of an object) that isn't set. Which most likely means that you're query is failing (`fetch()` supplying no data or an array).

Comment: What does `var_dump($select);` give you?

Comment: I try that sir but it gives me the same error message.

Comment: meaning the database are empty?

Answer (score 0):

When no records are found, fetch() return false. Your code evaluates count(false).

just remove -`>fetch()` as you want to count lines in a results set, instead of columns in a single record.

```
$count = count($db->pssale("F8", $textdate));
```

Actually, the cleanest way to go might be :

```
$count = $db->pssale("F8", $textdate)->count("F8");
```

As I think that code will exactly generate the SQL request you want.

If you're trying to count distinct values of F8, this time, you may write:

```
$count = $db->pssale("F8", $textdate)->count("DISTINCT F8");
```

Have a look at http://www.notorm.com/#api ; it's not that hard to read.

*Note*: I guess you didn't understand that you don't need to "execute" a query to get a result. NotORM is in charge of running the query as soon as it's needed. Don't put `fetch()` here and there unless you really want to get one record from a query (no foreach loop).